# Prevent setting birthday to something less than 13 years old in SEDE

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, data-explorer

From the legal section:

> Subscriber certifies to Stack Exchange that Subscriber is an individual (i.e., not a corporate entity) at least 13 years of age.

In your Stack Exchange Network's profile, setting birthday under 13 years is impossible.

Please make this the same for the Stack Exchange Data Explorer too.

Comment: I have updated your question quite a bit since it was very unclear on first read. Please check if this is what you want, and revert if necessary.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Thank you. Incidentally , I'm on the way of learning English.

Comment: Data Explorer is open source. We happen to have an age requirement, but other people who may choose to run it might not.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Age field in SEDE has been removed a while back for GDPR reasons, which means this request isn't relevant anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe it is just me, but I don't see the added value of this. I am not a legal expert, so I am not familiar with any of the legal application of what I am going to say next, but I actually don't care anything about that field and the validation on it.

If someone is too young to be a member on the site, he or she will just fill in another birth date than his or her actual birth date, so what purpose does the validation have? Just to circumvent enforcing law the easy way.

SEDE missing that validation is not relevant at all in my opinion.

Comment: Is it even necessary on SEDE? What personal information is linked to an account?

Comment: I am not sure what the law states about this, so it might be necessary to have it there, also because your SE profile isn't the only authentication provider.